# Why am I getting the error "tf.fromPixels is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have some basic tensorflow.js code [from an example on the documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#fromPixels):

```js
const image = new ImageData(1, 1);
image.data[0] = 100;
image.data[1] = 150;
image.data[2] = 200;
image.data[3] = 255;
const xs = tf.fromPixels(image);
xs.print();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

With this version (the one the website tells you to use):

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.0.0/dist/tf.min.js

And getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: tf.fromPixels is not a function` what might cause this? Are others getting this error when you run the snippet?

Comment: Tested in multiple browsers, same error.

Comment: I don't know much about tensor flow, tho: Did you take a look a what's in `tf`? Because JS rarely lies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation for version 0.12.0.

tf.fromPixels was deprecated in version 1.0.0, use: [tf.browser.fromPixels()](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#browser.fromPixels)